# Prevent Caching in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, caching, sql-server-2005

Having looked around the net using Uncle Google, I cannot find an answer to this question:

What is the best way to monitor the performance and responsiveness of production servers running IIS and MS SQL Server 2005?

I'm currently using Pingdom and would like it to point to a URL which basically mimics a 'real world query' but for obvious reasons do not want the query to run from cache. The URL will be called every 5 minutes.

I cannot clear out the cache, buffers, etc since this would impact negatively on the production server. I have tried using a random generated number within the SELECT statement in order to generate unique queries, but the cached query is still used.

Is there any way to simulate the NO_CACHE in MySQL?

Regards

Comment: Hi Mitch, we have 3 servers, an web, application and database server. Monitoring the front page does not represent the query time or responsiveness our users are experiencing, hence the 'real world query' being executed by a PHP script. I've amended the original question.

Comment: IIS and 2K5 are on separate servers.

Comment: "MySQL"? that came out of nowhere. i thought this question was about SQL Server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server does not have a results cache like MySQL or Oracle, so I am a bit confused about your question. If you want the server to recompile the plan cache for a stored procedure, you can execute it WITH RECOMPILE. You can drop your buffer cache, but that would affect all queries as you know.

At my company, we test availability and performance separately. I would suggest you use this query just to make sure you your system is working together from front-end to database, then write other tests that check the individual components to judge performance. SQL Server comes with an amazing amount of ways to check if you are experiencing bottlenecks and where they are. I use PerfMon and DMVs extensively. Using PerfMon, I check CPU and page life expectancy, as well as seeing how long my disk queue is. Using DMVs, I can find out if my queries are taking too long (sys.dm_exec_query_stats) or if wait times are long (sys.dm_os_wait_stats).

The two biggest bottlenecks with IIS tend to be CPU and memory, and IIS comes with its own suite of PerfMon objects to query, but I am not as familiar with those.

Comment: Hi Noel, the reason for asking is that I have a query which takes 10 seconds to execute first time round, the second time is takes only 2 seconds. Altering the client or date (still using the same table etc), it goes back to being 10 seconds for the first run, 2 seconds for subsequent runs.

Comment: Jim, it does sound like SQL Server is caching in memory the pages that you would otherwise being reading from disk, and thus you see different query times. I see that you're trying to prevent plan reuse through the random characters, but that will not cause your buffers to be dropped. Perhaps you should put a random sort order (ORDER BY NEWID()) in there if you're adding TOP x, or you should select a random range of rows each time, which would cause SQL to read from the disk (if those pages were not in memory from other queries).

Answer (score 33):

To clear the SQL buffer and plan cache:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
```

A little info about these commands from MSDN:

> Use DROPCLEANBUFFERS to test queries with a cold buffer cache without shutting down and restarting the server. ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187762.aspx))
>
> Use DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to clear the plan cache carefully. Freeing the plan cache causes, for example, a stored procedure to be recompiled instead of reused from the cache. ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx))

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this will clear the cache for the entire server, so running this on a production server might not be the best idea. It might also take anywhere from several seconds to half an hour to complete, depending on the number of databases and cached plans.

Comment: "without shutting down and restarting the server" => this saved my day :)