# SQL - slow only on first run...can't tell if my changes make it faster or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL script made of 3 queries that runs very slowly on the first run inside of SQL Management Studio (about 90 seconds).  Subsequent runs immediately after that only take 0-5 seconds.  Obviously, it's caching it.  I declare and use a few keys and variables at the top, and want to know if my script modifications are making a difference in performance, but I can't if it's always faster the second time.

What can I do to the T-SQL to make it NOT use the cached version?  I ask this because I want to play with the SQL to make it faster, but I can't tell if I'm making a difference because only the first time of running my script is slow.

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6702637/1089636

Comment: Yes, but I'm afraid it'd make everything very slow if FREEPROCCACHE is run against production environment.  I only really want to do this against just the query I'm running, but I suppose I could copy the data to a test DB.

Comment: Just using DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
seems to do the trick.  At least for my purposes in my test environment.  Not fully sure of the ramifications in production environment, but it works here while testing performance on query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` is your answer but do not run it in a production environment. This removes everything from the buffer cache and will result in a slow down that could cause a down time in a busy environment.

Do not confuse it with `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, which you also should never run in production. It clears out all of your cached query plans and will cause them all to have to go through recompilation. However, you can specify a plan handle to do this one at a time.

Comment: Thank you, running DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS worked great for me in my Dev environment and allowed me to determine if my query changes were making it run faster by not using the cached query plan every time.